# Is a multiple of a hyperelliptic curve hyperelliptic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a curve of genus 2 over $\mathbb{C}$. So $C$ is hyperelliptic, that is it admits a degree 2 map to $\mathbb{P}^1$. Is a power of $C$ say $nC$ hyperelliptic too, $n\geq 2$? It is not of genus 2 clearly.

The context is as follows. Consider $X=J(C)$, the Jacobian of the genus 2 curve. Consider the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(nC)$. I was wondering if there are curves in that linear system which are hyperelliptic.